# angular promise response.data is empty

Tags: angularjs, node.js, promise, angular-promise

factory:

```
angular.module('clientApp').factory('Di', function($http) {
  return {
    create: function(dis){
      return $http.post('/dis', dis);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('clientApp').controller('AdminCtrl', function($scope, toastr, Di) {
    $scope.di = {};
    $scope.dis = [];

    $scope.add = function(){
      Di.create($scope.di).then(function(response){
        console.log(response, 'front data post')
        $scope.dis.push(response.data);
        $scope.di= {};
      });
    };
  });
```

When I console.log() the response, the only thing I see in response.data is the hashKey. I do see the object in response.config.data, but from what I've seen online, this is just the original object i'm sending to the database, not the returned promise, right?

The data is saving to the database.

What am I doing wrong? I've done a similar configuration successfully with other promises, but the response is not what I'm expecting here.

API

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var DiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, lowercase: true , required: true },
  photo: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  year: { type: Number},
  timestamp: { type : Date, default: Date.now },
  description: { type: String},
  location: { type: Array },
  social: {
    website: {type: String},
    facebook: {type: String },
    twitter: {type: String },
    instagram: {type: String }
  }
});

DiSchema.methods.create = function(o, cb){
  this.model.save(o, cb);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('Di', DiSchema);
```

controller:

```
'use strict';

var Di = require('../models/di');

exports.create = function(req, res){
  Di.create(req.body , user, function(err, di){
    console.log('req.body.di', req.body);
    res.send({di:di});
  });
};
```

Routes:

```
var dis = require('../contollers/dis');
app.post('/dis', dis.create);
```

Comment: You have a typo, which may be the issue. Your `create` method on the service should have the parameter named `dis` instead of `di`. You're passing `dis` to the post, which is undefined.

Comment: Sorry is this the `post` or `get`?

Comment: It's the create `function(di){}`

Comment: yeah, it was confusing how I had it. I've corrected it. It was the post. Thank you for pointing out the typo. I do have 'dis' in my actual code. It still results in only the hashkey within response.data.

Comment: what are you sending back from the api? It might help for us to see the code for that too.

Comment: No problem. I've aded my backend code.

Comment: Is your server sending a response ? Doesn't seem like it

Comment: @NoobSter bit confused about what you are expecting as output

Comment: Can i ask, why you use factory when you can use " angular.service"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a typo with an extra parameter within your create function.

```
   exports.create = function(req, res){
  Di.create(req.body , function(err, di){
    console.log('req.body.di', req.body);
    res.send({di:di});
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should bind your promise to the scope. 
Would that fix the problem? Can you try?

```
$scope.add = function(){
  Di.create($scope.di).then(function(response){
    console.log(response, 'front data post')
    $scope.dis.push(response.data);
    $scope.di= {};
  }.bind($scope));
};
```